# How to completely script the process of importing SSL certificate and binding this certificate to a specific site

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, windows-server

I have been looking around for a solution for this problem that works across different versions of Windows Server & IIS, but so far I couldn't find a reasonable solution, what I need is some sort of a script or a command line tool, that takes a certificate file (pfx) for example and then either using the same script or tool find a way to configure one website to use this certificate.

Comment: for sysadmin questions better ask at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good script on TechNet

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/96ccb49f-b669-4e05-965e-3090984a3594.mspx?mfr=true

CertImport.vbs

```
Option Explicit
Dim iiscertobj, pfxfile, pfxfilepassword, InstanceName, WebFarmServers, IISServer
Set iiscertobj = WScript.CreateObject("IIS.CertObj")
pfxfile = WScript.Arguments(0)
pfxfilepassword = WScript.Arguments(1)
InstanceName = WScript.Arguments(2)
WebFarmServers = split(WScript.Arguments(3), ",")
iiscertobj.UserName = WScript.Arguments(4)
iiscertobj.UserPassword = WScript.Arguments(5)
For Each IISServer in WebFarmServers
  iiscertobj.ServerName = IISServer
  iiscertobj.InstanceName = InstanceName
  iiscertobj.Import pfxfile, pfxfilepassword, true, true
Next
```